# how to check a string dot preceding with another?

Tags: javascript, regex

here is my regexp which checks for links in input text.

```
message = message
        .replace(/(https?:\/\/)(www\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}(\.[a-z]{2,4})*/g,'<a href="$&" class="my_link" target="_blank">$&</a>')
        .replace(/(https?:\/\/){0}www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}(\.[a-z]{2,4})*/g,'<a href="http://$&" class="my_link" target="_blank">$&</a>');
```

which works with **http://google.com**, **https://google.com**, **http://google.co.in** ,**https://google.co.in**, **www.google.com** and **www.google.co.in**.
but not works for **http://www.google.com**.
what should i do for that?
if i input this URL, it outputs `www.google.com" class="my_link" target="_blank">http://www.google.com`
what should i do now?
thanks

update: for this link `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SukTBSJJ4KM&feature=g-vrec&context=G2d692eeRVAAAAAAAACA` it breaks at several points.
what is the regexp that should be added to read address after `http://www.youtube.com`

Comment: for www.google.com the output must be `<a href="http://www.google.com" class="my_link" target="_blank">www.google.com</a>`
and for the case i said it must be `<a href="http://www.google.com" class="my_link" target="_blank">http://www.google.com</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about:

```
message = message
    .replace(/(https?:\/\/|)((www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}(\.[a-z]{2,4})*)/g,'<a href="http://$2" class="my_link" target="_blank">$1$2</a>')
```

Edit according to question changes:

```
message = message
    .replace(/(https?:\/\/|)(\S+)/g,'<a href="http://$2" class="my_link" target="_blank">$1$2</a>')
```

Comment: now the problem is, this one not changes the whole link.
for example http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SukTBSJJ4KM&feature=g-vrec&context=G2d692eeRVAAAAAAAAC
it breaks at http://www.youtube.com and somewhere elase also.
what should i do to get the whole link
thanks

Comment: @KrishnaRajK: Please add in the question some inputs and the corresponding outputs required.

Answer (score 1):

Me done it..
little changes in the answer of M42 made it.

```
message = message
        .replace(/(https?:\/\/|)((w+\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,}(\.[a-z]{2,}){1,}(\/\S*)?)/g,'<a href="http://$2" class="my_link" target="_blank">$1$2</a>')
```

which works with all links.
thanks M42.
:D

Comment: Krishna, if the URL is at the end of a sentence and followed by a full-stop, then that full stop is going to be included and will break your links.  Edit: Actually, chrome and FF don't seem to mind!

Answer (score 0):

Try following pattern:

```
/(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
```

OR try this pattern:

```
var re = /(^|\s)((https?:\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\/\S*)?)/gi;
```

Comment: working for http://, https:// and http://www.
but not for www.
and if i use my code for www again, it will output the error output that i mentioned in the question.
is there any way to check http:// or https:// is not preceding for www. in the second condition?
that means for the links starting with www only and not containing http:// or https://
thanks for the reply.

Comment: for now me adjusted with replacing occurrence of `http://www.` or `https://www.` with just `www.` before these two steps.
give any other better method where can i use `http://www.` or `https://www.` as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it, see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/MWBFS/

Guts are:

```
/\b(www\.|http(s)*:\/\/)(\S+)/
```

Output from Fiddle is:

```
beginning <a href="http://google.co.in" class="my_link" target="_blank">google.co.in</a> end
beginning <a href="https://google.co.in" class="my_link" target="_blank">google.co.in</a> end
beginning <a href="http://google.com" class="my_link" target="_blank">google.com</a> end
beginning <a href="http://google.co.in" class="my_link" target="_blank">google.co.in</a> end
beginning <a href="http://google.com/" class="my_link" target="_blank">google.com/</a> end
beginning <a href="http://google.co.in/" class="my_link" target="_blank">google.co.in/</a> end
beginning <a href="http://www.google.com/" class="my_link" target="_blank">www.google.com/</a> end
beginning <a href="http://www.google.com/" class="my_link" target="_blank">www.google.com/</a> end
```